# Apache Atlas with Cassandra and Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, apache-atlas

I am trying to run Apache atlas with cassandra as the graph storage backend and ElasticSearch as the index backend. I am getting a 503 error when hitting localhost:21000 from my browser. I don't see any errors in the application log or the start up logs. The same set up works with hbase and solr.

How do i troubleshoot this further since I don't see any errros in the log?

Comment: providing the error log would be helpful and probably you would want to verify if you have set proper ES and Cassandra config in atlas-application.properties